# Setting up VS code for c++ on mac

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

I am trying to follow this guide exactly

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-clang-mac

Everything works fine until I reach the step "Debug helloworld.cpp", I am able to use the "tasks.json" file to build the .cpp file and run it in the command line. However as soon as I add the "launch.json" file outlined in "Debug helloworld.cpp" everything stops working and I get the following errors as soon as I try to debug.

```
expected ';' at end of declaration
range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
```

I have looked at many other stack overflow posts claiming that clang++ is defaulting to c++03 whereas I need to be using c++11, however the guide above uses
-std=c++17 as an argument.

The guide itself even provides the following related help at the bottom.

> If you see build errors mentioning "C++11 extensions", you may not have updated your task.json build task to use the clang++ argument --std=c++17. By default, clang++ uses the C++98 standard, which doesn't support the initialization used in helloworld.cpp. Make sure to replace the entire contents of your task.json file with the code block provided in the Build helloworld.cpp section.

Which I definitely did do as you can see in the tasks.json file I linked below, so I don't see what the problem could be.

Any help at all would be appreciated.

tasks.json file...

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-stdlib=libc++",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ]
}
```

launch.json file...

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "clang++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang++ build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json file...

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: I see two tasks defined (for some reason), and you only added the language version to one of them.... Tip: check which one you're using, to verify that it's the one you modified (hint: it's not)

Comment: Thanks @AsteroidsWithWings, the default task the guide had set to use did not include the -std=c++17 argument, adding that argument to the array fixed the problem.

Comment: Okay - perhaps you missed the _"Make sure to replace the entire contents of your task.json file with the code block provided in the Build helloworld.cpp section."_ part ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your `launch.json` calls the `"C/C++: clang++ build active file"` task. You want it to call your `"clang++ build active file"` task.

You don't need the `-stdlib=libc++` on a Mac.

Comment: Thanks changing the launch.json file to target the appropriate task did help when trying to debug, but running shift+cmd+B still caused the error. Adding the -std=c++17 argument to the second task as well which was set to be the default by the guide fixed the issue.

Comment: That's simply because of the `"isDefault"` flag not being moved. Your question text makes zero mention of wanting to execute the build task with a keyboard shortcut, only debugging, otherwise I would have mentioned that as well.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your `VSCode Debug Extension`, does little matter with configuration files.

Do not use Microsoft `C/C++`(Identifier: `ms-vscode.cpptools`, for C/C++
IntelliSense, debugging, and code browsing)!

Just use CodeLLDB to debug C++ on mac. Just use `CodeLLDBv1.4.5`. Do not use the latest version of CodeLLDB(`CodeLLDBv1.6.x` has caused much more [buggers since Nov 5, 2020](https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb/issues/387), and [never fix](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/148946). that bugger `version 1.6.10` has taken me seven days to config debug C++
with VSCode on mac, made me in trouble, made me depressed even masturbate 4 times in a week.).

Setup C++11 debug with VSCode on mac: [Details of successful configuration refer to here](https://gist.github.com/SofijaErkin/92144b34cb7b584875b61714ff425cd8).

Answer (score 0):

Under your tasks.json file, and "args" you may need to change "-std=c++17" to  "-std=c++11" instead, according to this post: https://bernieslearnings.com/c-expected-at-end-of-declaration/

since the error is that a 'range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]'